Multiplicities and double and triple tensor products of simple $\frak{g}$-modules
Given a complex simple Lie algebra $\frak{g}$ and a simple module $V_{\lambda}$ for some dominant weight $\lambda$. Consider the tensor product decomposition
$$
V_{\lambda} \otimes V_{\lambda} \simeq V_{\mu_1} \oplus \cdots \oplus V_{\mu_k}
$$
into simple summands. In all the examples I know, this decomposition has no multiplicities, that is to say the weights $\mu$ are pairwise distinct. What is an example of a dominant weight $\lambda$ for which there are multiplicities.
Examples: The first and second fundamental representations of $\frak{sl}_n$ and their duals. The first fundamental representation of $\frak{so}_{n}$ for $n$ even and odd.
By contrast, for the triple tensor product
$$
V_{\lambda} \otimes V_{\lambda} \otimes V_{\lambda}
$$
all the examples I know will have multiplicities. Is this always the case?
Examples: The first fundamental representation of $\frak{sl}_2$ and the adjoint representation of $\frak{sl}_2$.

Could you list some examples you know?

@LSpice: I have added some examples. I admit that for the second question my family of examples is quite small.

Let $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak{sl}_3$, and consider the adjoint representation $V=\mathfrak g$. Then $V\otimes V$ contains $V$ with multiplicity two; see for example page 14 of http://sporadic.stanford.edu/bump/sagedays/lie.pdf.
For part two, when $V_\lambda$ is the trivial representation clearly the tensor product $V_\lambda\otimes V_\lambda\otimes V_\lambda=V_\lambda$ is multiplicity-free. Otherwise $\dim(V_\lambda)>1$. Note that the $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$-representation $V\otimes V\otimes V$ has a $S_3$-action, and breaks up as $S^3V\oplus (S^{2,1}V)^2\oplus \wedge^3V$ (this is Schur-Weyl duality). Here $S^{2,1}V$ is non-zero when $\dim(V)>1$. The decomposition respects the $\mathfrak g$-action, so $V_\lambda\otimes V_\lambda\otimes V_\lambda$ must always have multiplicity!

Thanks for the counterexample! What about the second question? Can there exist a triple tensor power with no multiplicities?

@ZoltanFleishman I added an answer to the second part!

Great, thanks a lot! Can you explain in more detail what $S^{2,1}(V)$ is? In the expression $(S^{2,1}(V))^2$ does the superscript of $2$ mean a direct sum of the space with itself?

@ZoltanFleishman the tensor product $V\otimes V\otimes V$ has a $\Sigma_3$-action which permutes the factors and commutes with the $\mathfrak{gl}(V)$-action. The summand of $V\otimes V\otimes V$ corresponding to the trivial $\Sigma_3$-representation is the symmetric power $S^3V$, the one corresponding to the sign representation is the exterior power $\wedge^3V$, and the summand corresponding to the two-dimensional representation of $\Sigma_3$ is $(S^{2,1}V)^2$. The superscript of $2$ is the direct sum with itself as you say, and is the dimension of the corresponding $\Sigma_3$-representation.

Fantastic! Thanks a lot!
